# Delete file in hadoop excluding some files

Tags: unix, hadoop, awk, grep

I have hundreds of thousands of files with the format:

> CDR_IP2MSISDN_CYO-CGN-CC-YYYY-MM-NN_NN_NN_NN-N.csv.gz

where **MM** is the month, **YYYY** the year, and **NN** is an incremental counter. They are all in a directory of the hdfs and when I have to debug the folder and leave only the last month of backup and current
what i do is:

```
hdfs dfs -mv /temis_sesions_ip/bkp-cgnat/CDR_IP2MSISDN_CYO-CGN-CC-2021-07*.csv.gz /tmp/
hdfs dfs -mv /temis_sesions_ip/bkp-cgnat/CDR_IP2MSISDN_CYO-CGN-CC-2021-08*.csv.gz /tmp/
hdfs dfs -rm /temis_sesions_ip/bkp-cgnat/CDR_IP2MSISDN_CYO-CGN*.csv.gz
hdfs dfs -mv /tmp/DR_IP2MSISDN_CYO-CGN-CC-2021*.csv.gz /temis_sesions_ip/bkp-cgnat/
```

I had an idea to create a script where I could read the directory and read the files except for something
to do something like

```
for k in /temis_sesions_ip/bkp-cgnat/CDR_IP2MSISDN_CYO-CGN-CC* | grep SOMETHING | awk '{print $8}'`
do
   hadoop fs -rm $k
done
```

But my question is: how to create a grep or awk that lists all `*CDR_IP2MSISDN_CYO-CGN-CC-YYYY-MM-NN_NN_NN_NN-N.csv.gz*` and excludes, for example,
July ones `CDR_IP2MSISDN_CYO-CGN-CC-2021-07*.csv.gz` and august `CDR_IP2MSISDN_CYO-CGN-CC-2021-08*.csv.gz` in that grep **SOMETHING**

Then I see how to parameterize in **SOMETHING** the month and the year in the style of `CDR_IP2MSISDN_CYO-CGN-CC-${CURRENT_YEAR}-${CURRENT_MONTH}\*.csv.gz`

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk to split the filenames on dashes and then use patterns to print lines that you need. For example:

```sh
find | awk -F- '$4 == 2020 && $5 == 08' | xargs hadoop fs -rm
```

Will delete all files from august 2020.
It can be parametrized like this (note the quoting hell):

```sh
find | awk -F- '$4 == '"$CURRENT_YEAR"' && $5 == '"$CURRENT_MONTH" | xargs hadoop fs -rm
```

**Another option**, if you don't need the power of regular expressions for your queries is a simple:

```sh
find -name "*-*-2020-08-*" -exec hadoop fs -rm {} +
```

Which is easily parametrizable:

```sh
find -name "*-*-$CURRENT_YEAR-$CURRENT_MONTH-*" -exec hadoop fs -rm {} +
```

P.S. If you don't know what some part of any command does - put the command in https://explainshell.com/ and it will explain it to you :)

But if you still have any questions - feel free to ask.